# Collision detection and clipping issues in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection, game-physics

I've recently started putting together a little physics simulation from scratch, something I've never tried before, and I've run into an issue regarding the interaction between the collision of the objects I have on stage, and what I think is my constant gravity. I'm not sure if 200 lines of code is too large for here, but this is what I have.

```
package  {

    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;


    [SWF (width="1500", height="1000", frameRate="24")]
    public class ElasticityV2 extends MovieClip{
        /* Gravity is 9.8 m/s2, which for flash, since it's being applied every frame, needs to be 
        divided out by the frame rate as to not have super fast acceleration. GravMulti is to balance
        out gravity's speed, as it seemed a little slow after the framerate division. Resistance is acting
        like friction for now, and slows down the objects in the air and on the ground at the same rate.
        Elasticity is how bouncy each object is and how the force it recieves is applied*/
        public var gravMulti:Number = 5;
        public var gravity:Number = gravMulti *(9.8/stage.frameRate);
        public var resistance:Number = 0.98;
        public var elasticity:Number = 0.8;
        public var floor:Number = stage.stageHeight - 100;

        public var objectList:Array = new Array();
        public var shadowList:Array = new Array();
        public var yVelocityList:Array = new Array();
        public var xVelocityList:Array = new Array();
        public var massList:Array = new Array();
        public var frictionList:Array = new Array();
        public var lastXList:Array = new Array();
        public var lastYList:Array = new Array();
        public var elasticityList:Array = new Array();
        public var dragList:Array = new Array();

        public var spawnNum:int = 20;

        public var bounding:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,stage.stageWidth - 100,stage.stageHeight);

        public var distantBackground:Background = new Background();
        public var starLight:Light = new Light();


        public function ElasticityV2() {

            addChild(starLight);
            starLight.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
            starLight.y = -400;
            starLight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLightDrag);
            starLight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onLightDrag);
            starLight.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onLightDrag);

            for(var s:int=0;s<spawnNum;s++){
                var ballShadow:Shadow = new Shadow();
                addChild(ballShadow);
                setChildIndex(ballShadow,0);
                ballShadow.y = floor - (ballShadow.height/2);
                ballShadow.x = 100;
                shadowList.push(ballShadow);

                var ball:ElasticBall = new ElasticBall();
                var dragging:Boolean = false;
                addChild(ball);
                ball.y = 100;
                ball.x = s * 200;
                objectList.push(ball);
                yVelocityList.push(randomMe(20,-20));
                xVelocityList.push(randomMe(40,-40));
                massList.push(randomMe(20,5));
                frictionList.push(randomMe(0.6,0.01));
                objectList[s].width = objectList[s].height = massList[s] * 10;
                elasticityList.push(elasticity);
                dragList.push(dragging);
                ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDrag);
                ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onDrag);
                ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onDrag);
            }

            addChild(distantBackground);
            distantBackground.y = stage.stageHeight - distantBackground.height;
            distantBackground.width = stage.stageWidth;
            setChildIndex(distantBackground,0);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onGameLoop);

        }

        public function onGameLoop(e:Event):void{
            //checkCollision();
            for(var i:int=0;i<objectList.length;i++){
                updatePhysics(i);
                updateShadows(i,starLight);
            }
        }

        public function updatePhysics(objRef:int):void{
            if(lastXList[objRef] != undefined){
                if(lastXList[objRef] != objectList[objRef].x){
                    xVelocityList[objRef] = objectList[objRef].x - lastXList[objRef];
                }
            }

            if(lastYList[objRef]!= undefined){
                if(lastYList[objRef] != objectList[objRef].y){
                    yVelocityList[objRef] = 4*(objectList[objRef].y - lastYList[objRef])/stage.frameRate;
                }
            }

            if(objectList[objRef].y>= floor - objectList[objRef].height){
                yVelocityList[objRef] = -(yVelocityList[objRef] * elasticityList[objRef]);  
                objectList[objRef].y = floor - objectList[objRef].height;
            }
            if(objectList[objRef].y<= 0){
                yVelocityList[objRef] = -(yVelocityList[objRef] * elasticityList[objRef]);  
                objectList[objRef].y = 0;
            }
            if(objectList[objRef].x > (stage.stageWidth - objectList[objRef].width)){
                xVelocityList[objRef]=-xVelocityList[objRef];
                objectList[objRef].x = stage.stageWidth - objectList[objRef].width;
            }
            if (objectList[objRef].x <0){
                xVelocityList[objRef]=-xVelocityList[objRef];
                objectList[objRef].x = 0;
            }



            if(!dragList[objRef]){
                yVelocityList[objRef]+=gravity;
                objectList[objRef].y += yVelocityList[objRef];
                xVelocityList[objRef]= (xVelocityList[objRef] * resistance);
                if(-0.5<xVelocityList[objRef] && xVelocityList[objRef]<0.5){
                    xVelocityList[objRef] = 0;
                }
                objectList[objRef].x += xVelocityList[objRef];
            }
            lastXList[objRef] = objectList[objRef].x;
            lastYList[objRef] = objectList[objRef].y;

            if(xVelocityList[objRef] == 0){
                xVelocityList[objRef]=randomMe(90,-90);
                yVelocityList[objRef]=randomMe(90,-90); 
            }
        }

        public function onDrag(e:Event):void{
            if(e.type == "mouseDown"){
                setChildIndex(DisplayObjectContainer(e.target),numChildren - 1)
                e.target.startDrag(false,bounding);
                //xVelocityList[objRef] = yVelocityList[objRef] = 0;
                //dragging = true;
            }else{
                e.target.stopDrag();
                //dragging = false;
            }


        }

        public function onLightDrag(e:Event):void{
            if(e.type == "mouseDown"){
                e.target.startDrag(false,bounding);
            }else{
                e.target.stopDrag();
            }
        }

        public function updateShadows(objRef:int, lightSource:MovieClip):void{

            //-----Cut for convenience------
        }

        public function checkCollision():void{
            for(var v:int=0;v<objectList.length;v++){
                var ball1 = objectList[v];
                for(var w:int=v+1;w<objectList.length;w++){
                    var ball2 = objectList[w];
                    if((ball1.x + getRadius(ball1) + getRadius(ball2) > ball2.x) && (ball1.x < ball2.x + getRadius(ball1) + getRadius(ball2)) && (ball1.y + getRadius(ball1) + getRadius(ball2) > ball2.y) && (ball1.y < ball2.y + getRadius(ball1) + getRadius(ball2))){

                        var dx:Number = ball2.x - ball1.x;
                        var dy:Number = ball2.y - ball1.y;

                        var dist:Number = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));

                        if(dist < getRadius(ball1)+getRadius(ball2)){



                            var newX1:Number;
                            var newY1:Number;
                            var newX2:Number;
                            var newY2:Number;

                            trace("Magnitude 1 is : " + (Math.sqrt((xVelocityList[v] * xVelocityList[v]) + (yVelocityList[v] * yVelocityList[v]))));
                            trace("Magnitude 2 is : " + (Math.sqrt((xVelocityList[w] * xVelocityList[w]) + (yVelocityList[w] * yVelocityList[w]))));

                            newX1 = ((massList[v] * xVelocityList[v])+(massList[w] * xVelocityList[w]))/(massList[v] + massList[w]) * 2 - xVelocityList[v];
                            newY1 = ((massList[v] * yVelocityList[v])+(massList[w] * yVelocityList[w]))/(massList[v] + massList[w]) * 2 - yVelocityList[v];
                            newX2 = ((massList[v] * xVelocityList[v])+(massList[w] * xVelocityList[w]))/(massList[v] + massList[w]) * 2 - xVelocityList[w];
                            newY2 = ((massList[v] * yVelocityList[v])+(massList[w] * yVelocityList[w]))/(massList[v] + massList[w]) * 2 - yVelocityList[w];

                            xVelocityList[v] = newX1;
                            yVelocityList[v] = newY1;
                            xVelocityList[w] = newX2;
                            yVelocityList[w] = newY2;

                            ball1.x += newX1;
                            ball1.y += newY1;
                            ball2.x += newX2;
                            ball2.y += newY2;

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public function randomMe(high:Number, low:Number = 0):Number{
            return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
        }

        public function getRadius(obj:MovieClip):Number{
            return obj.width/2;
        }

        public function centerX(obj:MovieClip):Number{
            return obj.x + getRadius(obj);
        }

        public function centerY(obj:MovieClip):Number{
            return obj.y + getRadius(obj);
        }

    }

}
```

It's a very simple system to check for collision, just comparing the radius of the objects, and midair collisions seem fine, but if one ball lands on top of another that has no x or y velocity, it just sinks into it. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Maybe you should reduce a little your code to interesting parts. While it's cool being able to reproduce your application behavior, I'm not sure someone is gonna read all theses lines for such specific problem.

Comment: Please, check execution of this condition `if(dist < getRadius(ball1)+getRadius(ball2))` by the `trace` function.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your balls behave like this: When one ball lands on top of the other, that's actually lying on the ground, the other ball gets pushed down into the ground, then you react at it within updatePhysics() by placing it into the position where it originated, thus, those balls become one within another. One of the suggestions that could remedy this will be to hold last collided object for each of the balls for one cycle of physics, say like this:

```
if(dist < getRadius(ball1)+getRadius(ball2)){
    // process collision
    ball1.lastCollided=ball2;
    ball2.lastCollided=ball1;
}
```

Then, when you update your coordinates in updatePhysics(), check if lastCollided is null, if not, update that ball's coordinates and speed the same way, essentially simulating another collision. After checking for all the events within update physics cycle, assign null to lastCollided of all balls.